# Extract most recent data before a specific date

Tags: date, excel-formula, excel-2010

I'm struggling to do the following:

I have a list of product types (A,B,C... etc.) and want to extract the most recent value for each product that is relevant before a specific date.

Example:

[image: example]

In the above example, for all Type As (and Bs and Ms etc.) in column 'A', I want to extract the value in column 'B' that is the most recent before the date in 'F1' (i.e. 17/06/2008 in this instance).

In the actual list the 'TYPE' is not ordered alphabetically. I need to complete this task for multiple entries with multiple reference dates.

I would usually order column 'C' by date, delete the dates more recent than the reference date and use the function:

```
=iferror(index(B:B, match(E4, A:A, 0)), "-")
```

In the above example the correct values for extraction would be:

- A - 11
- B - 12
- M - 8

This process works but is still much slower than I would like. Does anyone have any ideas of how I can incorporate "<=F2" but ">='all other dates'" into the equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this array formula

```
=INDEX($B$4:$B$16,MATCH(1,($A$4:$A$16=E4)*($C$4:$C$16=MAX(IF(($A$4:$A$16=E4)*($C$4:$C$16<=$F$1),$C$4:$C$16))),0))
```

array formulas are confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Comment: The array formula has worked so far, I am yet to try it on a large dataset but it's looking promising, Thank you